# Refering ionic accordion elements having no id, class and element name

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver, ionic-framework, protractor, ui-automation

I'm not perfect in protractor but i worked with it a little bit in some projects. In my current test project I have faced ionic accordions and have no classes, ID and element name to access them. Here is the snipes code below

```
    <v-accordion role="tablist" class="vAccordion--default">

  <!-- ngRepeat: abt in about.about --><v-pane class="is-expanded" ng-repeat="abt in about.about" expanded="$first" style="background: white none repeat scroll 0% 0%;" ;="">
  <v-pane-header tabindex="0" aria-selected="true" role="tab"><div ng-transclude="">
        <h4 class="ng-binding" style="margin:15px">
        <i class="ion-ios-glasses-outline" style="color:#3498DB; font-size:25px" &nbps;&nbps;&nbps;&nbps;&nbps;&nbps;=""> </i>
          Vision
        </h4>
        <!-- <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i> -->
      <!-- <h2 ng-model ="abt.header"></h2> -->
    </div></v-pane-header><!-- <v-pane ng-repeat="domtax in domestictax.domestictax" expanded="$first"> -->



    <v-pane-content style="max-height: none;" role="tabpanel"><div ng-transclude="">
     <h5 class="ng-binding" style="margin:15px">  Curabitur et ligula. Ut molestie a, ultricies porta urna. Vestibulum commodo volutpat a, convallis ac, laoreet enim. Phasellus fermentum in, dolor. Pellentesque facilisis. Nulla imperdiet sit amet magna. Vestibulum dapibus, mauris nec malesuada fames ac turpis velit, rhoncus eu, luctus et interdum adipiscing wisi.</h5>
      <!-- <h2 ng-model ="abt.content"></h2> -->

      <!-- accordions can be nested :) -->
      <!-- ngIf: abt.subpanes -->
    </div></v-pane-content>
  </v-pane><!-- end ngRepeat: abt in about.about --><v-pane class="" ng-repeat="abt in about.about" expanded="$first" style="background: white none repeat scroll 0% 0%;" ;="">
  <!-- <v-pane ng-repeat="domtax in domestictax.domestictax" expanded="$first"> -->
```

What I need to test is whether the dummy text " Curabitur et ligula..." is displayed where the accordion text 'Vision' or icon is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

use css selectors, read [here](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.By.css)

basically the selector will be `by.css('v-accordion[role="tablist"]')`

Answer (score 0):

```
var Acordion = element(by.cssContainingText('v-pane-content', 'Curabitur et ligula'));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code could solve the problem, it is best to add elaboration and explain how it works for people who might not understand this piece of code.